# Qual a notação correta para aprender criação de arquivos de configuração do nodejs, bower, e outros?

Tags: php, json, aplicação-web

Qual a notação correta para especificar um arquivo JSON que tenha varias chaves e colchetes aninhados? vejo isso no bower, grunt, nodejs, npm, etc. e varios plugins de desenvolvimento web.

Comment: Imagino que te refiras ao `package.json`... nesse caso é JSON. Não percebo o que queres dizer com "aprender criação"... e o que queres dizer com "outros"? todos os tipos diferentes que existem na internet?

Answer (score 0):

Estás a referir-te ao format JSON (Javascript Object Notation). O formato é por exemplo isto:

```
{
"prop": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
],
"prop2": "wow"
```

}

Podes verificar se o que escreveste é json em http://jsonlint.com/ , copias lá o codigo e validas, o site diz-te se é json valido ou nao.

Basicamente é um objecto com propriedades, e esses podem ter propriedades também, só tens de ter cuidado em fazer "prop": "conteudo", atenção aos dois pontos e às aspas. Lembrar também que o ultimo elemento nunca tem vírgula.